# Among the different types of ANOVA data structures, which one(s) cannot be handled by multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, anova, linear

Well, we discussed several ANOVA data structures in class and yesterday the professor asked this question. We couldn't come up with a specific answer for this. What do you think, what types of ANOVAs cannot be handled by multiple linear regression? What are the reasons and what are the differences?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ANOVA data structures that cannot be handled by regression because OLS regression and ANOVA are the same model. In matrix terms, both are

$Y = X\beta + \epsilon $

Comment: Maybe the instructor thought abouts things like split splot which need mixed models for its handling?